# Line 10: ERROR: ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis | Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to create table but it shows error, "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis."

```
CREATE TABLE member
(member_id NUMBER(10)
CONSTRAINT member_member_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
last_name VARCHAR2(25)
CONSTRAINT member_last_name_nn NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR2(25),
address VARCHAR2(100),
city VARCHAR2(30),
phone VARCHAR2(15),
join_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
CONSTRAINT member_join_date_nn NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE title
(title_id NUMBER(10)
CONSTRAINT title_title_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR2(60)
CONSTRAINT title_title_nn NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR2(400)
CONSTRAINT title_description_nn NOT NULL,
rating VARCHAR2(4)
CONSTRAINT title_rating_ck CHECK
(rating IN ('G', 'PG', 'R', 'NC17', 'NR')),
category VARCHAR2(20),
CONSTRAINT title_category_ck CHECK
(category IN ('DRAMA', 'COMEDY', 'ACTION',
'CHILD', 'SCIFI', 'DOCUMENTARY')),
release_date DATE);

CREATE TABLE title_copy
(copy_id NUMBER(10),
title_id NUMBER(10)
CONSTRAINT title_copy_title_if_fk REFERENCES title(title_id),
status VARCHAR2(15)
CONSTRAINT title_copy_status_nn NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT title_copy_status_ck CHECK (status IN
('AVAILABLE', 'DESTROYED','RENTED', 'RESERVED')),
CONSTRAINT title_copy_copy_id_title_id_ pk
PRIMARY KEY (copy_id, title_id));
```

First two tables were successfully created, the third one 'title_copy' shows error at line 10 which is `PRIMARY KEY (copy_id, title_id));`

Comment: You are missing several commas, in lines 5 or 6 for instance. Can you add them and rerun?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE title_copy
(copy_id NUMBER (10),
title_id NUMBER (10)
CONSTRAINT title_copy_title_id_fk REFERENCES title (title_id),
status VARCHAR2 (15),
CONSTRAINT title_copy_status_nn NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT title_copy_status_ck CHECK (status IN
('AVAILABLE', 'DESTROYED','RENTED', 'RESERVED')),
CONSTRAINT title_copy_copy_id_title_id_ pk
PRIMARY KEY (copy_id, title_id));`

Comment: its said, "ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier."

Comment: That's an improvement. What's in line 6?

Comment: `CONSTRAINT title_copy_status_nn NOT NULL,`

Comment: Maybe you are missing something else earlier. Edit the question to show your current sentence, if you can. If you can't edit the question, you can paste current query in a paste web service, and link it here as comment.

Comment: I have updated it. please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace..:

```
[...]
CONSTRAINT title_copy_status_ck CHECK (status IN
('AVAILABLE', 'DESTROYED','RENTED', 'RESERVED')),
CONSTRAINT title_copy_copy_id_title_id_ pk
PRIMARY KEY (copy_id, title_id));
```

... by:

```
[...]
CONSTRAINT title_copy_status_ck CHECK (status IN
('AVAILABLE', 'DESTROYED','RENTED', 'RESERVED')),
CONSTRAINT title_copy_copy_id_title_id_pk
PRIMARY KEY (copy_id, title_id));
```

Note a removed space.